# Error with passing parameter to Typescript generic class with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want to use React Components for build a library.

I have a Component abstract class (the mother class component) with ComponentProps :

```typescript
import * as React from "react";

/**
 * Main components properties
 * */
export interface ComponentProps {
    ContainerId: string,
    Id: string,
    CssClass: Array<string>,
    Attributes: Map<String, String>,
    Events: Map<String, String>
}

/**
 * Main component class
 * */
export default abstract class Component<Props extends ComponentProps>
    extends React.Component<Props & ComponentProps, {}> {

}
```

And a TextBox class extends the Component abstract class, with TextBoxProps, extends ComponentProps :

```typescript
import * as React from "react";
import Component, { ComponentProps } from "../Component";
import { useState } from 'react';

export interface TextBoxProps extends ComponentProps {
    /**
     * Value of textbox
     * */
    Value: string,
    /**
     * Placeholder of textbox
     * */
    PlaceHolder: string
}

export default class TextBox<Props extends TextBoxProps> extends Component<Props & TextBoxProps> {
    render() {
        const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            console.log("New value : " + event.target.value);
        };

        return (
            <div id={this.props.Id + "_cnt"}>
                <input
                    defaultValue={this.props.Value}
                    placeholder={this.props.PlaceHolder}
                    onChange={handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I try to use the TextBox component with TextBoxProps, it's work on Visual Studio, but on Visual Studio Code, I have this error :

Generic type 'TextBox' requires 1 type argument(s). **ts(2314)**

[Visual Studio Code TextBox's error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5yKF.jpg)

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Edit : My current tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Default
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    // Added
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works properly for me. Could you upload your code or tsconfig file ?

Comment: @Amirhossein I upload my tsconfig in the question

Comment: Hmm it still works for me ! Could you upload your code on https://codesandbox.io/ or something else ?

Comment: @Amirhossein I have Github repository with everything, and the bug : https://github.com/marquito73/marquito-utils-react-lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code. There is a problem.

When you want to render something with react-dom, you should do it in .tsx file not .ts file.

Changing src/components/index.ts to src/components/index.tsx will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's works now ! I'm still a newbie to React and typescript